# Shuffling the lower triangle in a large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large, sparse adjacency matrix (64948 x 64948) that is symmetrical across the diagonal. What I need to do is randomize the locations of the nonzero elements in the upper or lower triangle of the matrix (which will then get transposed.) I have code that does this below. It works with 10x10 matrices, but not with 64948x64948 (I run into memory errors on a cluster). I realize my method might be flawed, and I would appreciate if anyone has any insight about how I could do this in a more efficient way!

First, I create "mask," which is essentially an array of every location in the lower triangle.

```
mask_mtx = np.ones([10,10]) #all ones
mask_mtx = np.tril(mask_mtx,-1) #lower triangle ones
mask_mtx = sparse.csr_matrix(mask_mtx)
mask = sparse.find(mask_mtx) #indices of ones
np.save('struc_conn_mat_mask.npy',mask) #cluster fails here when n=64948. I'm trying to save it out from a cluster so I can use the mask on my local machine with code below
len_mask = len(mask[0]) #how many indices there are
```

I create mtx as an array for the purposes of this example, but usually I will be reading in a 65k x 65k  csr_matrix. I then find the number of nonzero elements in the mtx lower triangle and randomly pick that many locations from the mask. I then put 1s at these locations in an empty tmp_mtx. Finally, I transpose the lower triangle to upper triangle.

```
mtx = sparse.random(10,10,format='csr',density=0.1) #for the purposes of this example, create random matrix
lmtx = sparse.tril(mtx,-1,format='csr') #lower triangle
tmp_mtx = np.zeros((10,10)) #empty lower triangle to set
lvals = sparse.csr_matrix.count_nonzero(lmtx) #how many 1s in lmtx?
coordinate_indices = random.sample(range(len_mask),lvals) #choose n=lvals random indices to fill with ones
for idx in coordinate_indices:
    tmp_mtx[mask[0][idx]][mask[1][idx]] = 1 #at randomly chosen index from mask, put a 1
tmp_mtx = sparse.csr_matrix(tmp_mtx)
mtx = tmp_mtx + tmp_mtx.T #transpose to upper triangle
```

Again, this works fine with 10x10 matrices, but fails at several places with larger matrices. Ultimately, what I want to do is a seemingly simple operation--shuffle the triangle--but I can't think of how to do it in a more efficient way. Perhaps there is some way of shuffling the columns and rows (but just for one of the triangles?)

Any help would be so, so appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: This is not the kind of task I (or probably anyone else) can run (or visutalize) in my head.  So the only way I can help is to take time to recreate the code on my machine (and looking at the intermediate steps).   But you say it runs on the smaller size, but fails in unspecified ways with unspecified larger shapes.  That's not an inviting thing to test.  Shuffling and indexing is not a `scipy.sparse` strong point.  Often it ends up using matrix-multiplication to do indexing

Comment: Even with 0.1 density, your sparse matrix will have 420 million entries, and that's going to take multiple gigabytes of memory.  It's 3.2 GB just for the numbers, plus the overhead to store the sparse coordinates and links.  You may need to think about your problem in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Representing brain connectomes is certainly a data challenge. Will be updating the post if I figure out anything new.

Comment: Look into tril_indices instead of tril and work in sparse space. Split into blocks if the distribution is uniform